# ¿Cómo debería llamar a un "waiter"?

Tags: vocabulario, españa

Español es mi tercer idioma (lo he estudiado durante cuatro años), y voy a España este verano.

No sé cómo llamar la atención de un camarero. Por ejemplo, la gente piensa que puede llamar a un camarero "garçon" en francés, pero es un poco grosero (y es como un turista).

¿Cómo puedo llamar la atención de un camarero de una manera delicada? ¿Puedo decir "camarero" o "camarera"?

Comment: En China hay ahora "waiters" que no son de hueso y carne: http://cnnespanol.cnn.com/2016/04/22/meseros-robots-debutan-torpemente-en-un-restaurante-de-china/ y se llama "Meseros"

Answer (score 6):

"Camarero" y "camarera" son perfectamente aceptables en España, aunque se pueden utilizar alternativas como "Oiga" o "Por favor".

Comment: Diría que _camarero_ o _camarera_ están quedando un poco en desuso. Como bien dices, _Oiga_, _Por favor_ son las más usadas, incluso palabras en la lína de _Perdone_ o _Disculpe_ son bastante usadas

Answer (score 4):

El uso es regional al parecer.
Encuentro que decir *camarero* o *camarera* no suena mal pero un poco *tosco*.
Sin embargo en mi país se acostumbra a decir *mesero* o *mesera*, aunque de todas formas igual se considera algo tosco.
Al menos cuando voy a un restaurante, generalmente me refiero a ellos como *joven* o *señorita*.

Comment: Igual en Colombia

Comment: No en España. Es más, aquí "joven" suena incluso más tosco que "camarero".

Comment: No diría yo que "joven" suene tosco, yo diría que "joven" lo usan sobre todo las personas mayores para dirigirse a personas visiblemente más jóvenes que ellos, incluyendo a los camareros. Si no eres una persona mayor, entonces usar "joven" para llamar la atención de alguien sí que suena raro.

Answer (score 4):

Una manera más de llamar a un "waiter" que aquí no se ha mencionado es "Mesero", que es el que atiende las mesas. Pero es un modismo regional que en algunas partes no se usa.

Comment: En España no se usa.

Answer (score 3):

En España se utiliza *camarero* cuando se habla de él, pero para llamarlo normalmente se le llama como a cualquier otra persona, no por su oficio.

"Perdone", "Disculpe". A veces tambien se usa "cuando puedas": "¿Me pones una cerveza cuando puedas?"

Answer (score 2):

Creo que para hombres "Joven" y para mujeres "Camarera"

Comment: ¿Y si el camarero no es joven?

Comment: En eso asunto, tal vez le agredezco.

Comment: Jaja :) Se entendería mejor tu comentario diciendo *En ese caso, tal vez se lo agradezca* o *en tal caso, ...*.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda!

Answer (score 2):

Joven y camarero, desde luego que no.
Mejor: "Perdone", "Perdona", "Disculpa", "Disculpe", "Cuando puedas".
Y "¡Jefe!" si quieres parece un nativo ;-)

Comment: En España se usan todas esas expresiones. Aunque llamar al camarero diciendo *¡jefe!* es un poco arriesgado si no se tiene un cierto dominio. En algunos sitios puede quedar muy bien, en otros muy mal.

Answer (score 1):

Coincido con Jano e I.G. Pascual, lo más habitual es *Por favor*, *Perdone* o *Perdona* (si es joven).

*Joven* no es muy conveniente utilizarlo y *mesero*, *mesera* o *garçon* no se usan en España en la actualidad.

Si hay mucho bullicio es muy conveniente usar el lenguaje gestual, o sea, levantar la mano, la mayor parte de las veces es más útil que llamarles.

Answer (score 1):

Me sumo a todas las respuestas sueltas que he encontrado por aquí. Para ordenar el concepto.

El **término apropiado** sería **"Camarero"** para los hombres o **"Camarera"** para las mujeres.

Según la [RAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6uEvTHn) como primera definición:

> m. y f. Persona que tiene por oficio servir consumiciones en restaurantes, bares u otros establecimientos similares.

En algunos paises de Latinoamérica se suele decir "Mesero" y "Mesera" para hombres y mujeres respectivamente.

Según la [RAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=P2SWeD0%7CP2YQnHz) esto confirma los lugares donde se utiliza (América Central, Bolivia, Chile, Colombia, Ecuador, México y Republica Dominicana)

> m. y f. Am. Cen., Bol., Chile, Col., Ec., Méx. y R. Dom. Camarero de
>   café o restaurante.

En Perú se suele la palabra "mozo" que para los Peruanos es normal pero la RAE la califica como una palabra para indicar cierta inferioridad.

Aquí 2 definiciones de la palabra mozo de la [RAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=PyCDtud%7CPyIxduT)

> 5. m. y f. Persona que sirve como criado, en especial la destinada a un menester determinado. Mozo de cuadra. Moza de mesón.
> 6. m. y f. Empleado de categoría inferior, que realiza servicios para los que no se precisa gran cualificación. Mozo de estación, de café.
>      Moza de hotel.

Para los Colombianos la palabra mozo significa "amante".

**EN RESUMEN**

De una manera neutra podrías decir, como muchos dicen en sus respuestas, lo siguiente:

**JOVEN** para los muchachos o **SEÑORITA** para las chicas si son personas "relativamente" joven.

Cuando la persona se encuentre cerca simplemente puedes llamar su atención diciendo con respeto "DISCULPE" o para ser más amigable podrías de una manera más informal decir "DISCULPA". Depende mucho de la persona a la que te dirijas y en su forma de tratar a las personas.

No te recomiendo decir JOVEN, SEÑORITA o DISCULPE cuando la persona está relativamente lejos porque tendrías que gritar o levantar la voz y eso se podría interpretar como de mala educación.

A mi parecer, si la persona se encuentra lejos creo que el lenguaje universal de levantar la mano cuando te vea para llamar su atención es lo más adecuado.

Comment: Aqui hay una historia con "Mozo": http://www.gocomics.com/espanol/luannspanish/2015/12/14

Answer (score 1):

En casi todos los paises latinos se usa "camarero". Es muy decente usar esta difición, pero si quieres usar algo mas coloquial podrías llegar a usar hasta la palabra "amigo/a" (lo recomiendo en lugares de confianza).

Pero lo mejor que podrias hacer es decir:

Si esta se encuentra lejos: *Disculpe camarero/a*

Y si está cerca podrías usar: *Disculpe Señor/Señorita*